# Graph with multiple x and y axis using Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, mplot3d

As I checked with the Matplotlib document and other [resources](https://sites.google.com/site/scigraphs/home/posts/multibleyaxesparasiteaxes).
I got that when multiple axis were created they are not depend on each other and we can plot the multiple line as per different axis. 
But I need to plot the graph like two Y-axis contains with the temperature as (Celsius and Fahrenheit) and need to plot only one single line related to that so with 1st axis user able to check Celsius and with 2nd axis Fahrenheit. with x-axis as range (1 -24 hr).

Suggestions are most welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `twinx()` to show two axes, and convert the y_limits of `ax1` in Celsius to y_limits of `ax2` in Fahrenheit:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from random import randint

x = range(1,24)
y = [randint(0,75) for x in x]

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()

ax1.plot(x,y)
y_lim  = ax1.get_ylim()

y2_lim = [x*9/5 + 32 for x in y_lim]

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.set_ylim(y2_lim)

ax1.set_ylabel('deg C')
ax2.set_ylabel('deg F')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the guide, but while I do this it makes the 1st y-axis to the static so when I zoom in the graph is not changing the measurement, is that any function or library that need to use for this.

Comment: The way you provided is working with the plt.show() but its not working with the mpld3.show(). I need to plot the graph in the web page.

Comment: Yes, but is there any solution for this or any other library that provide me this ?