# How to create grouped bar chart with secondary y-axis on matplotlib python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I just started to learn and work with python. I am facing trouble when I am trying to create a grouped bar chart with the secondary y-axis.

Here are the code for just now and the result

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, graph1=plt.subplots(figsize=(20,5))
graph2 = graph1.twinx()
graph1.bar(data_trans3['ITEM_NAME'],data_trans3['nett_profit'],width=0.3)
graph2.bar(data_trans3['ITEM_NAME'],data_trans3['QTY'],width=0.3)
```

[image]

What should I do to create the grouped bar chart with the **x-axis** as **item_name** and **y-primary axis** as the **nett_profit** while the **y-secondary axis** as the **QTY**.

I am sure that the code above is in the form of a simple bar chart.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Graph with multiple x and y axis using Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42506819/graph-with-multiple-x-and-y-axis-using-matplotlib)

Comment: I was done to create secondary axis. My issue is on create the grouped bar chart. I confused to combining between create secondary axis with the grouped bar chart.